# List encrypted object in S3 using python boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I am trying to move files from a S3 bucket in one account(source account) to S3 bucket in another account(destination account)
I am using sagemaker notebook so I have a sagemaker role.
I also have a role in my team account  which has full s3 access and fullsagemaker access and in the trust relationship i have given the destination account role arn and sagemaker role arn.
The destination account also has my team role arn and sagemaker role arn in its trust policy.

I am trying to assume my team role and then I will assume the destination role to copy files.

```
import boto3
                sts_client = boto3.client('sts')
            assumed_teamrole_object = sts_client.assume_role(DurationSeconds=1800,
                                                             RoleArn='myteamrole',
                                                             RoleSessionName='test1')
                assumed_destrole_object = sts_client.assume_role(DurationSeconds=1800,
                                                             ExternalId='externalid provided by destination account',
                                                             RoleArn='destination account role',
                                                             RoleSessionName='test2')
    temp_credentials = assumed_destrole_object['Credentials'] 
    session=boto3.session.Session(aws_access_key_id=temp_credentials['Access KeyyId'],
                                    aws_secret_access_key=temp_credentials['SecretAccessKey'],
                                    aws_session_token=temp_credentials['SessionToken'],
                                    region_name = 'us-east-1') 
    client = session.client('s3', aws_access_key_id=temp_credentials['AccessKeyId'],
                                    aws_secret_access_key=temp_credentials['SecretAccessKey'],
                                    aws_session_token=temp_credentials['SessionToken'],
                                    region_name = 'us-east-1')
    
        response = client.list_objects(Bucket='source bucket')
        print(response)
```

When I am running the above script I a getting the error :

**An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the ListObjects operation: Access Denied**
The objects in the source bucket are encrypted. Do I have to add any-permissions to decrypt on my end? Not sure why i am not able to list objects.

Comment: I don't think you are showing us your actual code, because it refers to `client.list_objects()`, but `client` does not exist.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I have update the code. Sorry for the error

Answer (score 1):

When copying files between S3 buckets that belong to different AWS accounts, you will need a **single set of credentials** that can **read from the source bucket** and **write to the destination bucket**.

If, instead, you are using two different credentials, then you will need to download the file with one set of credentials and then upload with another set of credentials, rather than copying the object in one operation.

Therefore, I recommend that you **use one set of credentials** (eg the `myteamrole` IAM Role) and then:

- Attach a policy to the IAM Role that permits GetObject access on the source bucket, and
- Attach a **bucket policy** to the destination bucket in the other AWS account that permits PutObject access from the above IAM Role

This will permit the `CopyObject()` operation with the one set of credentials.

I also recommend specifying `ACL = bucket-owner-full-control` when copying the object. This will grant ownership of the object to the destination AWS Account, which can avoid some permission problems. This will also require `PutObjectAcl` permissions on the Bucket Policy.

Comment: I am only using one set of credentials from myteam role. I also have the bucket policies attached on source and destination accounts. I am just able to list the objects not sure why

Comment: Your code is using `assumed_destrole_object` to list the Source bucket. Presumably, the IAM Role in the destination account does not have permission to access the source bucket in the originating account.

Comment: The source team has mentioned that they have onboarded the destination role  to list, get and decrypt .

Comment: The error message is saying that `destination account role` does not have permission to list `source bucket`. Since the role belongs to a different account than the S3 bucket, it would need a Bucket Policy on the S3 bucket to permit cross-account access by the role.

Comment: I have to update bucket policy on destination account? Also do I need to add permissions on the destination bucket to decrypt?

Comment: I know that my destination account role has put permissions. I need to copy all the files from from source account, can i just try this.                     
 source_bucket = 'source bucket'
destination_bucket = 'destinationbucket name'
for obj in source_bucket.objects.all():
    client.Object('destinationbucket', obj.key).put(Body=obj.get()["Body"].read())

Comment: Please read my answer. One set of credentials needs both Read access on the source bucket and Write access on the destination bucket. You will want to use the `copy_object()` method.